# is this possible not to use laravel passport default migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I don't want to use the passport default migration, is it possible, and also i want to use tow model for login authentication, customer, and admin sign up (different table), how do i do it? I have done this

`composer require laravel/passport`

now im stopping here `php artisan migrate`, why we need this what if we have our custom table for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the passport migrations and customize them

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations.
```

Comment: i will change user_id to customer_id, but what about the admin_id?

Comment: Do not worry abt them. Actually a customer and an admin are all ```users``` so i would rather you leave it as ```user_id``` but make sure your ```Customer``` and ```Admin``` class are ```Authenticatable```

Comment: sure, look into Passport multi-auth